# Why I am unable to squash these commits on magit?

Tags: magit, git

I am trying to squash some commits using magit. I tried two different approaches choosing different commit ids to pick and squash. Despite the fact that none of them worked out, the error messages varied. Unfortunately, I cannot understand any of them.

I did a [gif](https://github.com/pdelfino/public-notes/blob/main/magit-doubt-squash.gif) to show what happens and I put it on github.

How can I solve this? What should I try? Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you squash a commit, it is squashed *into the previous non-squashed* commit.  You're marking the very first commit in the list as a commit to be squashed, so there's no prior non-squashed commit to squash it into.  It's a bit like starting a new repository and using `git commit --amend` before you've made your first commit.

You need:

```
pick this commit
squash into ^
squash into ^
```

Note also that Git's rebase listing runs from top-to-bottom chronologically, as opposed to the log which is in reverse-chronological order.

---

Note that this isn't actually an Emacs/Magit question -- the point of confusion is no different in the standard Git UI.