# cannot 'squash' without a previous commit

Tags: magit

Emacs 27.1

Magit

I want to squash some my commits.

Here steps:

```
     1. magit-status (C-M-s)
     2. l (little L)
     3. l (log current)
     4. In the commit history, put the cursor on the oldest of the N commits that we want to squash, and press r(rebase)
     5. i (interactive)
     6. s (squash)  
     7. We can see that the two commits are marked as squash now,
        then we can press C-c C-c to make the squash happen.
        It will prompt you to enter the new commit and also hint 
        you the previous commit messages. Type Add fruits and 
        press C-c C-c
```

And here screens:
[image]

[image]

[image]

And when press `C-c C-c` I get error:

Press `$`

```
  1 git … rebase -i --autostash fedbec4\^
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Waiting for Emacs...
error: cannot 'squash' without a previous commit
You can fix this with 'git rebase --edit-todo' and then run 'git rebase --continue'.
Or you can abort the rebase with 'git rebase --abort'.
```

Comment: You should mark the first commit as `pick` and the rest as `squash`.

Comment: Nick, you should make that an answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I am unable to squash these commits on magit?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66466/why-i-am-unable-to-squash-these-commits-on-magit)